# Using an ActionListener to check for a specific instance from and then add to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, event-handling, jframe, actionlistener

I have created an GUI that accepts the following fields (name, street, city, state, zip, account number). In addition you are able to choose between 3 customer Types from a panel and finally a course from a drop down course ComboBox.

When the user types in the above information and clicks “SUBMIT”, the program will create the customer if they don’t exist and put them on the customer list, find the selected course on the course list and ask the user if they wish to enroll in the course with a confirmation pop up dialog.  If the user selects YES, the course is added to that customer’s course list, the fields are cleared, the cursor is placed in the name field, and another entry is possible.  If the customer already exits, a new customer is not created, but the course is added to that customer’s course list.
When the user clicks “FINISH”, the program writes to the prompt each customer and their course list, displays the dialog box of invoices, then exits.
Anonymous actionListeners are used. I need to have a method for `clearFields`, `addCourse` that accepts the customer name and the course title, `addCustomer` that uses the data in the fields to create customers and add them to the customer list, `readCourses` that reads `courses.txt`, creates the courses and adds them to the course list, and populates the string array used for the drop down box selections, and `generateInvoice`. This is as far as I have got.

```
submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
          if (confirm())
    {
                customerList.add(new Customer(nameField.getText(),new Address(streetField.getText(), cityField.getText(), stateField.getText(), Integer.parseInt(zipField.getText())), Integer.parseInt(accountNumberField.getText())));
            }

    clearFields();            
        }
    });

    finishButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
        {
            for(Customer c: customerList)
                System.out.println(c.toString());

            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    add(nameLabel);
    add(nameField);  
    add(streetLabel);
    add(streetField);
    add(cityLabel);
    add(cityField);  
    add(stateLabel);
    add(stateField);
    add(zipLabel);
    add(zipField); 
    add(accountNumberLabel);
    add(accountNumberField);

    add(customerLabel);
    add(myPanel);

    add(courseLabel);
    add(courseBox);

    add(submitLabel);
    add(submitButton);

    add(finishLabel);
    add(finishButton);
}   

public static void main(String args[])
{
    CourseGUI g = new CourseGUI();

    g.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    g.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    g.setSize(650,350);

    g.setVisible(true);
}   

public void clearFields()
{
    nameField.setText("");
    streetField.setText("");
    cityField.setText("");
    stateField.setText("");
    zipField.setText("");
    accountNumberField.setText("");
    myGroup.clearSelection();
courseBox.setSelectedIndex(0);

nameField.requestFocus();
}

public String getCourse()
{
   return courses[courseBox.getSelectedIndex()];        
}

public String getClassification()
{
if (studentButton.isSelected())
return studentButton.getText();
else if (facultyButton.isSelected())
return facultyButton.getText();
else 
return governmentButton.getText();
}

public boolean confirm()
{
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

int result;

String message;

message = String.format("%s %s %s %s %s %d %d", nameField.getText(), streetField.getText(), cityField.getText(), stateField.getText(), zipField.getText(), accountNumberField.getText());

result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, message);

if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        return true;
return false;
}
```

What I need help with is the coding inside my submitButton. addActionListener. How would I check to see if a customer already exist and if not then add them to the `customerList`.
Assume all other classes and arrayList needed are already created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `equals()` method in your `Customer` class that compares all the fields that you deem should determine if two customers are duplicates or not. For example, the following compares only the *account numbers* (and assumes they would never be `null`):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Customer) {
        Customer other = (Customer) obj;
        return this.getAcNumber().equals(other.getAcNumber());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can establish if a `Customer` already exists in the `List` using `indexOf()`. The `List` implementation would automatically use our `equals()` method above for comparisons.

```
if (confirm()) {
    Customer new = new Customer(nameField.getText(),new Address(streetField.getText(),
    cityField.getText(), stateField.getText(), Integer.parseInt(zipField.getText())),
    Integer.parseInt(accountNumberField.getText()));

    int existing = -1;
    if ((existing = customerList.indexOf(new)) != -1) {
        Customer old = customerList.get(existing);
        // Add course to existing customer
    } else {
        customerList.add(new);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you would have another `List` for *courses* in your `Customer` class, so that you can add multiple *courses* to existing *customers*.

Comment: can you explain what you have done from (int existing = -1.......) and yes I have another ArrayList called courseList.

Comment: *`List#indexOf()` returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.* So, if `existing != -1`, the customer already exists in `customerList` at index `existing`.

Comment: I have to implement another method called `addCustomer()`  that is responsible for using the data from the fields to create customers and add them to the arrayList. How would I incorporate all of this with what you have suggested

Answer (score 0):

The sweet ArrayList has a "contains" method and it really is. More info about [ArrayLists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
if(!customerList.contains(new Customer(nameField.getText()))
{
  customerList.add(new Customer(nameField.getText(),new Address(streetField.getText(), cityField.getText(), stateField.getText(), Integer.parseInt(zipField.getText())), Integer.parseInt(accountNumberField.getText())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a fully functional, you should define how a Customer and Address object equal with each others. The best way to do this is to override equals() and hashcode() functions Here is an example For Customer, you can apply the pattern for Address object:

```
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private Address address;
    private String accountNumber;

    public Customer(String name, Address address, String accountNumber) {
        // your put constructor code
    }

    // put your getting and setting methods here

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)  
            return true;  
        if (obj == null)  
            return false;  
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())  
            return false;  

        Customer otherCustomer = (Customer) obj;  

        // define how the names equals
        if (this.name == null) {  

            if (otherCustomer.getName() != null) {  
                return false;
            }

        } else if (!this.name.equals(otherCustomer.getName())) {
            return false;
        }

        // define how the accountNumber equals
        if (this.accountNumber == null) {  

            if (otherCustomer.getAccountNumber() != null) {  
                return false;
            }

        } else if (!this.accountNumber.equals(otherCustomer.getAccountNumber())) {
            return false;
        }

        //define how the Address equals
        if (this.address == null) {  

            if (otherCustomer.getAddress() != null) {  
                return false;
            }

        } else if (this.address.equals(otherCustomer.getAddress())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return  false;
        }

        return true;

    };

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
         final int prime = 31;  

            int result = 1;  
            result = prime * result 
                    + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode()) 
                    + ((accountNumber == null) ? 0 : accountNumber.hashCode())
                    + ((address.getCityField() == null) ? 0 : address.getCityField() .hashCode()) 
                    + ((address.getStateField() == null) ? 0 : address.getStateField() .hashCode())
                    + ((address.getStreetField() == null) ? 0 : address.getStreetField() .hashCode())
                    + address.getZipField();

            return result;  

    }
 }
```

and then in your addActionListener() function check if your customer already existed or not:

```
Customer newCustomer = new Customer(nameField.getText(),new Address(streetField.getText(), cityField.getText(), stateField.getText(), Integer.parseInt(zipField.getText())), Integer.parseInt(accountNumberField.getText())));

    if (!customerList.contains(newCustomer)) {
        customerList.add(newCustomer)
    }
```

Comment: I have to implement another method called addCustomer() that is responsible for using the data from the fields to create customers and add them to the arrayList. How would I incorporate all of this with what you have suggested

Comment: Could you explain why you have to implement addCustomer() function ?. All add customer action displayed at my second blockquote. If you must do this just simply add the quote to your function.

Comment: It is just a requirement of the code I am writing, what do you mean I can add the quote to the function?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. But you have to  override hashCode and equals for your Address class base on my Customer class and update appropriate parameters for your addCustomer() function.